# Solve a Partial Differential Equation without boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve this PDE, that doesn't have any boundary condition.

$ u_y + uu_x=1 $

$ u=0$   in   $y=x^2$

I already found that

$u(s)=s$

$x(s)= \frac{s^2}{2} + x_0$

$y(s)= s+ x_0^2$

With the conditions $x(0)=x_0,$ $y(0)=x_0^2,$ $u(0)=0$

The problem now is that I can't find a way to transform the function $u(s)$ to a function $u(x,y)$.

Does someone as an idea?
Thank you

Comment: How exactly did you obtain your solutions in a variable s

Comment: @Triatticus I used the methods of characteristics. I considered the curve (x(s),y(s),u(s)) in $\mathbb{R}^3 and I supposed those conditions for s=0.

Comment: Ah I see now I was going to suggest that but wasn't sure of what you did

Comment: According to the given condition, I found this solution on the form of an implicit equation : $$u-y+\left(x-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)^2=0$$. Is it consistent with your result ?

Answer (score 0):

You do have a boundary condition, it is $u=0$ on the parabola $y=x^2$.

To finish the problem, you need to find for a given point $(x,y)$ in the plane which characteristic curve passes through that point, and the value of $s$ at which it exactly hits $(x,y)$. So you need to solve the system of equations

$$x = \frac{s^2}{2}+x_0$$
$$y = s + x_0^2$$

for $s=s(x,y)$ and $x_0=x_0(x,y)$ as functions of $x$ and $y$. Then your solution is $u(x,y)=s(x,y)$.

EDIT: Let me add that if you sketch your characteristic curves, you will find that they pass through the boundary $y=x^2$ twice, and the value of $u$ is not zero both times. So your solution will only be defined locally, and is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_y+uu_x=1$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{1}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{1}$ :
$$u-y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{1}$
$$u^2-2x=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ :
$$\boxed{u-y=F(u^2-2x)}$$
F is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the specified condition.

Condition : $u(x,x^2)=0$
$$0-x^2=F(0-2x)$$
Let $X=-2x\quad\implies\quad x=-\frac12 X$
$$0-\left(-\frac12 X\right)^2=F(0-2x)=F(X)$$
$$F(X)=-\frac14 X^2$$
So the function F(X) is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=u^2-2x$ .
$$u-y=-\frac14 \left(u^2-2x\right)^2$$
$$\boxed{4(u-y)+(u^2-2x)^2=0}$$
This is the implicit equation for $u(x,y)$ which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.

If you want the explicit $u(x,y)$ solve the polynomial quartic equation for $u$.

NOTE :

This is exactly the result that you correctly obtained with two parameters $x_0$  and $s$ . Just eliminate the two parameters from your three equations  $u=s\quad;\quad x= \frac{s^2}{2} + x_0 \quad;\quad y= s+ x_0^2$.